# What is the matrix of inertia of a thin rectangular plate?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I only want to get sure how the matrix looks like,

Is it : $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{Mb^2}{3} &0  &0 \\ 
 0&\frac{Ma^2}{3}  & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & \frac{M(a^2+b^2)}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$

Or not ?(a=length,b=width,M=mass)

Comment: I'd replace $3$ with $12$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors

Comment: It's not written as a matrix

Comment: On wiki I mean.

Comment: Can you make a proof on how to calculate the entries please ?

Comment: On that web page, look at "Solid cuboid of width w, height h, depth d, and mass m" and take h = 0. The proof is a simple integral, to be found on any textbook.